# how to set an alert for server working or not in AppDynamics?

Tags: appdynamics

how to set an alert for server up/Down in AppDynamics?

I tried to set an alert for whether the server is working or not but I didn't see any policy in AppDynamics. can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Health Rule](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/23.x/latest/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/health-rules) using the [Machine Agent "Availability" metric](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/22.3/en/infrastructure-visibility/hardware-resources-metrics#id-.HardwareResourcesMetricsv22.1-MachineMetrics) for a Critical and / or Warning [condition](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/23.x/latest/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/health-rules/health-rule-conditions) (for example check if zero every minute for 5 minutes).

If you want to add "alerting" have a look at setting up a [Policy](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/23.x/latest/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/policies) which does [Actions](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/23.x/latest/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/actions) (such as emailing alerts), configure this to be triggered by events created by your Health Rule